# C# Mime Types class

Tags: c#, .net, mime-types

I want to save a Mime Type in my code.
Now I use to do this:

```
string mYMimeType = "text/plain";
```

Is there a way to save it in a (already existent) standard,dedicated class?
Something like...

```
Http.MimeTypes myMimeType = Http.MimeTypes.TextPlain;
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can make use of `MediaTypeNames` class exists in `System.Net.Mime` namesapce.

Below is .net class can help you , you dont have to create it by youself.

```
namespace System.Net.Mime
{
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the media type information for an e-mail message attachment.
    public static class MediaTypeNames
    {

        // Summary:
        //     Specifies the kind of application data in an e-mail message attachment.
        public static class Application
        {
            // Summary:
            //     Specifies that the System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application data is not
            //     interpreted.
            public const string Octet = "application/octet-stream";
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Specifies that the System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application data is in
            //     Portable Document Format (PDF).
            public const string Pdf = "application/pdf";
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Specifies that the System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application data is in
            //     Rich Text Format (RTF).
            public const string Rtf = "application/rtf";
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Specifies that the System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application data is a SOAP
            //     document.
            public const string Soap = "application/soap+xml";
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Specifies that the System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application data is compressed.
            public const string Zip = "application/zip";
        }

        // Summary:
        //     Specifies the type of image data in an e-mail message attachment.
        public static class Image
        {
            // Summary:
            //     Specifies that the System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image data is in Graphics
            //     Interchange Format (GIF).
            public const string Gif = "image/gif";
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Specifies that the System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image data is in Joint
            //     Photographic Experts Group (JPEG) format.
            public const string Jpeg = "image/jpeg";
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Specifies that the System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image data is in Tagged
            //     Image File Format (TIFF).
            public const string Tiff = "image/tiff";
        }

        // Summary:
        //     Specifies the type of text data in an e-mail message attachment.
        public static class Text
        {
            // Summary:
            //     Specifies that the System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text data is in HTML format.
            public const string Html = "text/html";
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Specifies that the System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text data is in plain text
            //     format.
            public const string Plain = "text/plain";
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Specifies that the System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text data is in Rich Text
            //     Format (RTF).
            public const string RichText = "text/richtext";
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Specifies that the System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text data is in XML format.
            public const string Xml = "text/xml";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why a standard like .net doesn't have all mediatypes, but only a few? I can't understand :-) However, Thanks for the reply

Comment: They don't even have `text/json` or `application/json`, wow. 

Comment: Oh that's not true. Since dotnet core 2.1 MediaTypeNames.Application.Json has been defined.

Comment: The `MediaTypeNames` class does sadly not seem to be a good choice. For example, using NET6, the media type `Image` only includes `Gif`, `Jpeg` and `Tiff`. Png is not included even though it has been a mainstream format for at least 15 years.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method to get mime type by file extension `MimeTypeMapper.GetMimeType(".xlsx")`
Here is an example of implementation:

```
public static class MimeTypeMapper
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, string> _mappings =
        new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        {
            {".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},
            {".xlsb", "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12"},
            {".xlsm", "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12"},
            {".xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
            {".xlt", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},
            {".xltm", "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12"},
            {".zip", "application/x-zip-compressed"},
        };

    public static string GetMimeType(string extension)
    {
        if (extension == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("extension");
        }
        if (!extension.StartsWith("."))
        {
            extension = "." + extension;
        }
        string mime;
        return _mappings.TryGetValue(extension, out mime) ? mime : "application/octet-stream";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the list of inbuild MimeTypes has been broadened since the answer proided Pranay Rana in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47886437/9660245

Below is the current simplified list of values

```
namespace System.Net.Mime
{
    public static class MediaTypeNames
    {
        public static class Text
        {
            public const string Plain = "text/plain";
            public const string Html = "text/html";
            public const string Xml = "text/xml";
            public const string RichText = "text/richtext";
        }

        public static class Application
        {
            public const string Soap = "application/soap+xml";
            public const string Octet = "application/octet-stream";
            public const string Rtf = "application/rtf";
            public const string Pdf = "application/pdf";
            public const string Zip = "application/zip";
            public const string Json = "application/json";
            public const string Xml = "application/xml";
        }

        public static class Image
        {
            public const string Gif = "image/gif";
            public const string Tiff = "image/tiff";
            public const string Jpeg = "image/jpeg";
        }
    }
}
```